# Scoping Problems with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, scoping

I have no idea as to why I no longer have access to my variables. Basically, I am under the assumption that when the appendUnitsIfHasValue function runs, it should have access to width, length, height, and weight. I should be able to manipulate the variables as well.

Note: the console.log prints "I SHOULD HAVE ACCESS TO STUFF"; however, the program explodes once it reaches the next line. It says that " Uncaught ReferenceError: width is not defined "

Ultimately, I want to be able to have access to the variables when I call the function and be able to change the values contained within the CreateItem function. Thank you in advance for the help!

```
CatalogApp.prototype.createItem = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  submittedForm = this
  var name = submittedForm["name"].value
  var description = submittedForm["description"].value
  var width = submittedForm["width"].value
  var length = submittedForm["length"].value
  var height = submittedForm["height"].value
  var weight = submittedForm["weight"].value
  that.appendUnitsIfHasValue(width, length, height, weight)
}

CatalogApp.prototype.appendUnitsIfHasValue = function(a,b,c,d) {
  console.log("I SHOULD HAVE ACCESS TO STUFF")
  if (width != "") {width+=' '+DIMENSIONSUNIT} else {width = "N/A"}
  if (length != "") {length+=' '+DIMENSIONSUNIT} else {length = "N/A"}
  if (height != "") {height+=' '+DIMENSIONSUNIT} else {height = "N/A"}
  if (weight != "") {weight+=' '+WEIGHTUNIT} else {weight = "N/A"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have access to those variables. They're defined in the scope of the `createItem` function and are only accessible within that function.

Are you trying to do something like

```
CatalogApp.prototype.appendUnitsIfHasValue = function(a,b,c,d) {
  if (a != "") {a+=' '+DIMENSIONSUNIT} else {a = "N/A"}
  if (b != "") {b+=' '+DIMENSIONSUNIT} else {b = "N/A"}
  if (c != "") {c+=' '+DIMENSIONSUNIT} else {c = "N/A"}
  if (d != "") {d+=' '+WEIGHTUNIT} else {d = "N/A"}
}
```

Comment: I thought that due to functional scoping I would still have access to the variables similar to the following: var x = 5; increment = function() {x = x + 1}; increment()